# Custom cumsum() in pandas with select rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate a cumulative sum column using the following custom formula for each derived column Z1, Z2:

```
Z1 += X (previous day end) * Y (current)

Z2 = Z1 + X (current)
```

So I only want Z1 to add the previous day's end if it has changed. Is this possible to do in pandas? How would I go about doing this?

The challenge is I only want the last snapshot of X from **previous day**, and I can't just do `df['X'].shift(3)` since some rows may be missing

Here is my sample df structure and desired output (Z1 and Z2):

| timestamp | X | Y | Z1 (derived) | Z2 (derived) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-09 14:00:00 | 100 | 5 | NA | NA |
| 2021-11-09 15:00:00 | -100 | 5 | NA | NA |
| **2021-11-09 16:00:00** | **-200** | **5** | **NA** | **NA** |
| 2021-11-10 14:00:00 | 800 | 10 | -1000 | -200 |
| 2021-11-10 15:00:00 | 900 | 10 | -1000 | -100 |
| **2021-11-10 16:00:00** | **1000** | **10** | **-1000** | **0** |
| 2021-11-11 14:00:00 | 400 | 20 | 9000 | 9400 |
| 2021-11-11 15:00:00 | 100 | 20 | 9000 | 9100 |
| 2021-11-11 16:00:00 | 500 | 20 | 9000 | 9500 |

I can't really change up this structure since this is a subset of a much larger table. Ideally I want to be able to parallelize this with pandarell

Comment: you may #1 `reindex` to add rows for those missing dates and do the `shift` things, or #2 use `df.set_index('timestamp')['X]` as a mapping Series and then use `map` for retrieving `X (previous day end)`. In either way you need to define how to treat missing Xs which you have not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! For missing Xs I would want the last existing snapshot of previous day. If entire previous day missing, then skip calculation